# Why selenium finds the same element at list which has deferents parents

Tags: python, selenium

I can't understand why it returns me the same element? If I just print the outerHTML of each element in els, it shows that all of them different. But when I run code below, it shows the same.

```
link = 'https://www.tme.eu/ru/katalog/vykliuchateli-kontsevye_100405/?s_field=1000012&s_order=asc&limit=20&currency=EUR&visible_params=2%2C2193%2C2019%2C1390%2C938%2C936%2C82%2C32%2C42%2C49%2C1391%2C20x5%2C694%2C725%2C695%2C1395%2C13%2C1385%2C11%2C1605%2C2390%2C412%2C45%2C413%2C708%2C157%2C757%2C707%2C98%2C1386%2C693%2C117%2C193%2C22%2C23%2C2412%2C1393%2C699%2C698%2C436%2C2556&mapped_params=2%3A131%3B'

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver-2')
d.get(link)

els = d.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="c-product-row__td "]')
for q in els:
    el = q.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="c-product-row__symbol-h4"]')
    print(el.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Output is:

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  d = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver-2')
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
<h4 class="c-product-row__symbol-h4">MAM1F11Z11</h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the same element all the times because

```py
q.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="c-product-row__symbol-h4"]')
```

finds the first element matching the `//*[@class="c-product-row__symbol-h4"]` XPath locator starting from the beginning of the page.
To find element inside (below) specific element you shoud add a dot `.` in the front of the XPath

```py
q.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@class="c-product-row__symbol-h4"]')
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not seeing the same element but different elements but the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) are having identical text i.e. ***MAM1F11Z11*** within the `<h4>` tags identified through the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
//*[@class="c-product-row__symbol-h4"]
```

Snapshot:

[image: 20elements]